# Error: cannot find symbol super.paintComponent(g) in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paintcomponent

I seem to get the error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
        super.paintComponent(g);
             ^
  symbol: method paintComponent(Graphics)
```

very often in my code.  I always seem to fix it, but this is always after as much as an hour of hair pulling trying to find the solution on a coding thread from 5 years ago.  Also, I never seem to remember what I did. So, I am finally asking the graphics pros here.  I wrote a little test program that should display a coordinate plane on the JFrame, but instead, I receive this error.  I am fairly new to graphics in java, so I have not tried much, except calling repaint on all sorts of components.  This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Graph extends JFrame {
        public void showFrame(){
                setSize(400, 400);
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JPanel plane = new JPanel();
                add(plane);

                setVisible(true);
                repaint();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
                Graph graph = new Graph();
                graph.showFrame();
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawLine(200, 0, 200, 400);
                g.drawLine(0, 200, 400, 200);
        }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) doesn't have this method. It has

```
 public void paintComponents(Graphics g)
```

inherited from `java.awt.Container`.

Comment: Yep, paintComponent is for JPanel.  Thank you.

Comment: This is *one* of the reasons that custom painting should be done in a `JPanel` rather that a top-level container like `JFrame`.

Comment: BTW - we should ***never*** overrides `paintComponents` (with an `s`) whether it is inherited from `JFrame` *or* `JComponent`. Leave it as is.

Comment: @AndrewTompson Yeah, I fixed it so the class extends JPanel and it uses paintComponent.